# Python: List Comprehension invalid syntax error

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to recreate this loop in one line:

```
results = [149, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 14, 0, 2] 

for x in results:
  total = x + total

print(total)
```

But when I do this:

```
 y = [total = total + x for x in results]
```

I get an error:

```
y = [total = total + x for x in results]                                                                                                                                       
                   ^                                                                                                                                                                   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: use `y = sum(results)`

Comment: Thank you. Did you know why we can't use "=" in a comprehension list?

Comment: `[total = total + x for x in results]` is' not a comprehensión list. The sintax is wrong by `=`. Use `sum()`

Comment: Because it is not a valid syntax in list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you only need is using a function:

```
results = [149, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 14, 0, 2]
res = sum(results)
print(res)
```

Or

```
from functools import reduce
results = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, results)
print(results)
```

If you insist to use **list comprehension**, I would say it troublesome and unnecessary since it will create another list which ultimately leads to the same approach to using functions to get **the summation** anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because a one-liner in python returns an array, it has not a clean way to refer to the objects it is creating itself.

You can't make a commutative sum, you could multiply the numbers (but each one of them)

```
In [2]: y = [x*x  for x in results]

In [3]: y
Out[3]: [22201, 0, 16384, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 196, 0, 4]
```

The best way to accomplish what you want is with its build in method `sum`

```
In [9]: sum(results)
Out[9]: 294
```